# Send Javascript value to PHP with Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phaser-framework

I want to send a javascript variable to php, and from PHP I like to store this in a database.

Now when I search on Google, a lot of information is visible to do this. Most times I see AJAX, but when I use AJAX this code doesn't run. I tried this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm and tried some answers on Stackoverflow.

Maybe it won't work because I use Phaser, a framework. Maybe I'm trying too long and I don't think clearly anymore, so I need a fresh look at this.

On my Phaser game I have different prefabs. One is called gameOver.js and I can have access to the score by this line of code:

```
var score = this.game_state.score;
```

That's easy. Ok, now I have to send it to PHP. I used the jQuery selector (jQuery.post() and jQuery.ajax()) and the tutorial from above, but without success.

At the moment I have this in my Javascript:

```
Game.GameOver.prototype.submitScore = function () {

   var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
   try{

      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){

      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {

         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){

            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }

   var score = this.game_state.score;
   var queryString = "?score=" + score ;

   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "senddata.php" + queryString, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

And this in senddata.php

```
$score = $_GET['score'];
echo "score:" . $score;
```

I guess that the last part isn't that easy, but I can't figure it out! So hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: What is the response of your request?

Comment: Seems not very good supported by browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to send a GET request to a page in jQuery you should be able to use something like the following:

```
Game.GameOver.prototype.submitScore = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'senddata.php?score=' + this.game_state.score
    })
    .done(function () {
        console.log('done');
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('failed');
    });
}
```

This works as expected with jQuery 2.2.0 and Phaser 2.4.4.